# How to have multiple unwraps for respective textures on one object?

Tags: uv

I am trying to add two textures onto one object with an add shader and want to control two different unwraps for them, but to my observation it's constrained to one unwrap which changes the unwrapping of the first texture when moved.

Comment: I think you can input two different UV maps into the shader, but I’m not sure. There is a mesh data panel that allows you to switch UV maps around.

Answer (score 1):

To use different *UV Maps* on one mesh you can simply do the following (suppose you already have a first map):

1. Go to the *Object Data Properties* (the green triangle) and under *UV Maps* hit the Plus symbol.
2. A new *UV Map* is created, usually named "UVMap.001" if the first one isn't renamed from "UVMap". In the *UV Editor* window you won't see a change, because the new UV map will automatically inherit the data from the first map.
3. However, in the *UV Editor* window you can now change the UVs to whatever you need them to be rotated, scaled etc.
4. In the *Shader Editor* you can add the different UV maps for example by adding *Input* > *UV Map* nodes and plug them into the *Vector* inputs of image textures etc. or maybe choose them in other nodes if they have UV options etc.

[image: uv_map_1]

[image: uv_map_2]

[image: uv_map_3]